How to prevent double click on submit button in chrome
I want to disable submitting form twice. Users often double click on submit button and then form is submitted twice. I already tried following Javascript, but does not work:


const btn = document.querySelector("#buttonid");
btn.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
const button = document.querySelector("#buttonid");
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  document.getElementById("buttonid").disabled = true;
});
$('#buttonid').prop("disabled", true);
<button ondblclick="this.disabled=true;">submit</button>




FYI: The posted snippet is not running as there is no button with the id buttonid

... although the last part <button ondblclick="this.disabled=true;">submit</button>, works fine for me in a Chromium-based browser. Can you elaborate on the "not working", please?

The problem is probably not the fact that users are double clicking, they are clicking once, but the server/script takes to long to respond (to their taste) and they click another time, resulting in two clicks (and not a double-click)

@ Can you elaborate on the "not working", please? ... if you click fast twice form is submitted twice, button gets "disabled" but form is submitted twice

Why don't you just remove the event listener after the first click?

@Why don't you just remove the event listener after the first click ... I tried each of above solution single ... not working

Works fine for me - demo

found problem - was caching on server

@matin delete the question then. Both question and answers has no value.

You can disable the button on after a single click.


const button = document.querySelector("#buttonid");
var clickFunc = ()=> {
  button.disabled = true;
}
 
#buttonid{
padding: 10px 24px;
border: solid 2px;
color: green;
border-radius: 6px;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: .7px;
background-color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}

#buttonid[disabled]{
color: #ddd;
cursor: default;
}
<button onclick="clickFunc()" id="buttonid">Submit</button>




Use the onsubmit form event. In this way the button wont get disabled on validation errors, only when submited.


const myFunction = () => {
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
  submitButton.disabled = true;
}
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input id="submitButton" type="submit">
</form>



